# How to prevent menu from opening anywhere except under button

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

On a tablet (iPad Pro shown), if I double tap the screen to zoom in on the page, and then click to open the Menu, the menu opens under the search box but should open below the header but aligned with the logged in user.

[image: Wrong menu position]

The expected behavior is that it will always open below the logged in user offset vertically below the header.

[image]

The html pretty much looks like below. I am using flex to position the items in the header (e.g., logo, search, user) but that shouldn't impact the menu. According to the material docs (v1.1.8) `By default, md-menu will attempt to align the md-menu-content by aligning designated child elements in both the trigger and the menu content.` Which implies that the menu will line up as desired to the `div` which wraps the button,icons, and name even if I didn't already have the `md-menu-origin` attribute.

What would cause a zoomed tablet to cause the menu to open in the wrong location?

```
<md-menu-bar>
<md-menu hide show-sm show-md md-offset="0 9">
    <div
        class="md-icon-button"
        ng-click="vm.openMenu($mdMenu, $event)"
        aria-label="Open portal menu"
        md-menu-origin
        md-menu-align-target
        role="button"
        aria-label="Portal menu"
    >
        <span class="fa fa-user-o"></span>
        <span class="user-name" ng-bind="vm.userName"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down" ng-if="!$mdMenuIsOpen"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-caret-up" ng-if="$mdMenuIsOpen"></span>
    </div>
    <md-menu-content layout="column" layout-align="start stretch" width="3">
       <span>Portal Menu</span>
       <md-menu-item>...</md-menu-item>
       <md-menu-item>...</md-menu-item>
       <md-menu-item>...</md-menu-item>
   </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
</md-menu-bar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with css property set for the same.

Use `position` to two elements and set `z-index` to the two elements on which opened dropdown is getting overlapped.

Example:

(parent element)

```
.class1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

(child element)

```
.class2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 16;
}
```

Once, check with this. This answer is from CSS point of view.